# How to Predict future temperatures based on past data with years

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-science-model

Hello everyone I am new to Machine learning and predicting. I just want to know if I can predict future temperatures based on past year's data and how I can do it Thanks. here is the pic of the dataset. what I am saying is.  Is there a way to predict temperatures based on the year column Thanks?

[image: open me]

Answer (score 1):

Predicting temperature is often framed as a time series problem. Given the seasonal effects, a simplifying assumption is that each month can be predicted separately.

You can start with a baseline model like taking all previous years for a single month and predict the average temperature.

From there, you can try more advanced models like fitting a line for year-over-year change for a given month.